# ASP.NET Core Web API - FluentValidationMvcExtensions.AddFluentValidation(IMvcBuilder, Action<FluentValidationMvcConfiguration>)' is obsolete

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, fluentvalidation

In ASP.NET Core-6 Web API, I am using FluentValidation.AspNetCore(11.2.1).

I have this code in the Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddMvc().AddFluentValidation(fv => {
    fv.DisableDataAnnotationsValidation = true;
    fv.RegisterValidatorsFromAssembly(typeof(Program).Assembly);
    fv.RegisterValidatorsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    fv.ImplicitlyValidateChildProperties = true;
    fv.ImplicitlyValidateRootCollectionElements = true;
    fv.AutomaticValidationEnabled = true;
});
```

But I got this error with all the code above highlighted:

> FluentValidationMvcExtensions.AddFluentValidation(IMvcBuilder, Action)' is obsolete: 'Calling AddFluentValidation() is deprecated

How do I get this resolved?

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked into [the documentation](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/aspnet.html)? Perhaps especially the section labeled [Automatic Validation](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/aspnet.html#automatic-validation). This is no longer recommended.

Comment: Why are you using AddMVC()?

Comment: I think it's version issue I changed from FluentValidation.AspNetCore(11.2.1) to FluentValidation.AspNetCore(11.0.0) and its works. Thanks

Comment: I would recommend use the latest version and change the code.

Comment: It seems that you are having [`compatibility issue`](https://github.com/FluentValidation/FluentValidation.AspNetCore#compatibility-with-aspnets-built-in-validation). You should set `AutomaticValidationEnabled ` to `false` to resolve the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the documentation (https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/aspnet.html) it is not recommended to use Automatic validation.

So I will recommend to not use Automatic Validation and remove the AddMvc() because automatic validation works with AddMvc, https://github.com/FluentValidation/FluentValidation/issues/1377

Now Let's come to your problem, assuming you are using .net6, following code should work.

```
using FluentValidation.AspNetCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddFluentValidation(conf =>
{
 conf.RegisterValidatorsFromAssembly(typeof(Program).Assembly);
 conf.AutomaticValidationEnabled = false;
});
```

Answer (score 7):

Add below methods for fluent auto validation. This will also fix the obsolete warning

```
builder.Services.AddFluentValidationAutoValidation();
builder.Services.AddFluentValidationClientsideAdapters();
builder.Services.AddValidatorsFromAssembly(typeof(SignUpRequestModelValidator).Assembly);
```

Answer (score 2):

I also got a similar error.

Try to install the fluentValation.AspNetCore package 11.1.2 and below.

Error resolved.

I hope it works for you

Answer (score 1):

We can check the documentation from FluentValidation at this URL: https://github.com/FluentValidation/FluentValidation/issues/1965

For example:

```
// Before 
services.AddFluentValidation(options => {
  options.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<MyValidator>();
});

// After migration:
services.AddFluentValidationAutoValidation();
services.AddFluentValidationClientsideAdapters();
services.AddValidatorsFromAssemblyComtaining<MyValidator>();



// Before: Enabling auto-validation and disabling clientside validation
services.AddFluentValidation(config => 
{
  config.ConfigureClientsideValidation(enabled: false);
});

// After: Enabling auto-validation only
services.AddFluentValidationAutoValidation();



// Before: Disabling auto-validation and leaving clientside validation enabled:
services.AddFluentValidation(config => 
{
  config.AutomaticValidationEnabled = false;
});

// After: Enabling client validation only:
services.AddFluentValidationClientsideAdapters();
```